# Appending vector issue Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to append a vector of 1's before the first column. However, anytime I try to insert the vectors, It always happens to the end of the array.

[Here is the current code I have written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvrUV.png)

```
x1 = np.array([0.100, 0.200, 0.250, 0.350, 0.400, 0.450, 0.500, 0.600, 
0.750, 0.800, 0.850, 0.900])

mu1 = np.array([0.000, 0.333, 0.667, 1.000])
mu2 = np.array([0.000, 0.167, 0.333, 0.500, 0.667, 0.833, 1.000])
s= 0.3
y_train = [0.603, 0.986, 0.891, 0.834, 0.572, 0.353, -0.085, 
-0.371,-0.967, -0.989, -0.749, -0.382]

y_train=np.array(y_train)
basis_function1 = [[0 for i in range(0,4)]for j in range(0,12)]
basis_function2 = [[0 for i in range(0,7)]for j in range(0,12)]
result1=[]
result2=[]



for x in x1:
    for m in mu1:
        a= np.exp(-((x-m)**2)/2*s**2)
        result1.append(a)


for x in x1:
    for m in mu2:
        a= np.exp(-((x-m)**2)/2*s**2)
        result2.append(a)

result1= np.reshape(result1, (12,4))
result2= np.reshape(result2, (12,7))
vectorOnes= np.ones((12,1))


result1 = np.append(result1,vectorOnes, axis=1)
np.insert(result1, 0, 1, axis=1)

print(result1)
print(result2)
```

Comment: List append always adds at the end.  `np.insert` has different syntax and behavior.  Don't confuse the two.  Also we discourage the use of `np.append`.  Learn to use `np.concatenate` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @hpaulj, you can use [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), using `vectorOnes` as the first, and `result1` as the second. This will concatenate the two arrays in the order that you provide them. Reproducing the relevant parts of your code:

```
result1 = np.random.random((12,4))
vectorOnes= np.ones((result1.shape[0],1))

>>> result1
array([[0.24082843, 0.31800901, 0.01556211, 0.32774249],
       [0.41475486, 0.90611202, 0.00791056, 0.49544814],
       [0.22842928, 0.97168093, 0.1808639 , 0.32310355],
       [0.99674441, 0.97379065, 0.7482597 , 0.9397243 ],
       [0.37714731, 0.94101763, 0.73416157, 0.36625995],
       [0.16470904, 0.97471554, 0.58262108, 0.67246731],
       [0.40309562, 0.88545376, 0.40600242, 0.06040476],
       [0.65425856, 0.15789502, 0.09350497, 0.49837995],
       [0.65652148, 0.00545527, 0.68244463, 0.38962242],
       [0.4012334 , 0.67545283, 0.09977628, 0.18019942],
       [0.67110475, 0.45046098, 0.24962163, 0.71436953],
       [0.32890942, 0.6090705 , 0.71712907, 0.35790405]])
>>> vectorOnes
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])

new_results = np.concatenate((vectorOnes, result1),axis=1)
>>> new_results
array([[1.        , 0.24082843, 0.31800901, 0.01556211, 0.32774249],
       [1.        , 0.41475486, 0.90611202, 0.00791056, 0.49544814],
       [1.        , 0.22842928, 0.97168093, 0.1808639 , 0.32310355],
       [1.        , 0.99674441, 0.97379065, 0.7482597 , 0.9397243 ],
       [1.        , 0.37714731, 0.94101763, 0.73416157, 0.36625995],
       [1.        , 0.16470904, 0.97471554, 0.58262108, 0.67246731],
       [1.        , 0.40309562, 0.88545376, 0.40600242, 0.06040476],
       [1.        , 0.65425856, 0.15789502, 0.09350497, 0.49837995],
       [1.        , 0.65652148, 0.00545527, 0.68244463, 0.38962242],
       [1.        , 0.4012334 , 0.67545283, 0.09977628, 0.18019942],
       [1.        , 0.67110475, 0.45046098, 0.24962163, 0.71436953],
       [1.        , 0.32890942, 0.6090705 , 0.71712907, 0.35790405]])
```

Alternatively, you *could* use `np.append`, remembering that the order in which you provide your arrays is the order the arrays will appear in your new array (so just flip the order of `result1` and `vectorOnes`). However, I wouldn't recommend this because [`np.append` basically calls `np.concatenate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932176/6671176), and you might as well use `concatenate`

```
>>> np.append(vectorOnes, result1, axis=1)
array([[1.        , 0.24082843, 0.31800901, 0.01556211, 0.32774249],
       [1.        , 0.41475486, 0.90611202, 0.00791056, 0.49544814],
       [1.        , 0.22842928, 0.97168093, 0.1808639 , 0.32310355],
       [1.        , 0.99674441, 0.97379065, 0.7482597 , 0.9397243 ],
       [1.        , 0.37714731, 0.94101763, 0.73416157, 0.36625995],
       [1.        , 0.16470904, 0.97471554, 0.58262108, 0.67246731],
       [1.        , 0.40309562, 0.88545376, 0.40600242, 0.06040476],
       [1.        , 0.65425856, 0.15789502, 0.09350497, 0.49837995],
       [1.        , 0.65652148, 0.00545527, 0.68244463, 0.38962242],
       [1.        , 0.4012334 , 0.67545283, 0.09977628, 0.18019942],
       [1.        , 0.67110475, 0.45046098, 0.24962163, 0.71436953],
       [1.        , 0.32890942, 0.6090705 , 0.71712907, 0.35790405]])
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the advice!