# How to use append for 2D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, append

I am trying to add array `y` to array `x` by this code:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((5,2))
y = np.array([[1,2]])
np.append(x , y)
```

But the result of `x` is yet:

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Don't use `np.append`.  Too many people use it wrong.  It is not a clone of the list append method.

Comment: You have a (5,2) array, and a (1,2).  Why not just `np.concatenate((x,y),axis=0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((5,2))
y = np.array([[1,2]])
result = np.concatenate((x,y), axis = 0)
```

Comment: It seems it's better than `append` cause could keep the dimension after concatenation.

Comment: You can check the difference in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932101/numpy-append-vs-concatenate. Top comment says that _`np.append` uses `np.concatenate`_

Comment: K.Maj your answer does not answer the question. The question was about: Why x does not change the value?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.append(x, y)
```

you are missing x assignment

Comment: Thanks. But it seems it changes `x` from a 2D array to 1D array. Is it possible to keep the shape too?

Comment: this is 2nd question.