# Numpy Array Lists not successfully appending all integers

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, timing

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

poslist = []
numlist = []
i = 1

num = int(input('Number to check?'))
plt.title(str(num) + ': Collatz Graph')
plt.xlabel('Step')
plt.ylabel('Value')
print(num)
poslist.append(poslist, i)
numlist.append(numlist, num)

while True:
    i = i + 1
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num // 2
        print(num)
    elif num == 1:
        break
    else:
        num = num * 3
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
        poslist.append(poslist, i)
        numlist.append(numlist, num)

print('Number Array:', numlist)
print('Position Array', poslist)
plt.plot(*(poslist, numlist))
plt.show()
```

When I use the `listname.append(listname, var)` NumPy functions, it skips over most of the variables. It only adds every 3rd or 4th variable to the list. The same is true for the step counter array. Even when adding a `time.sleep(4)` function, it appears to calcuate 3 or 4 numbers at once - only logging the first one.

Comment: correct your code and dedent your two last appends

Comment: I surprised it runs at all.  `alist.append(alist,1)` raises a TypeError, too many arguments.  The correct syntax is `alist.append(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two issues.

1. Your `append` command is for a `np.array` but `poslist` and `numlist` are `list` types. For those it would just be `numlist.append(num)` and `poslist.append(i)`. Instead of [`numpy.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) you want the [list version](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp).
2. As diggusbickus pointed out, your append statements in your while loop are inside an if statement and you need to push them back so they are outside of it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import numpy as np <--- You are not using numpy

poslist = []
numlist = []
i = 1

num = int(input('Number to check?'))
plt.title(str(num) + ': Collatz Graph')
plt.xlabel('Step')
plt.ylabel('Value')
print(num)
poslist.append(i) # <--- Change append statement for list
numlist.append(num) # <--- Same as above

while True:
    i = i + 1
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num // 2
        print(num)
    elif num == 1:
        break
    else:
        num = num * 3
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
    poslist.append(i) # <--- Shift out of if/else statement and change append
    numlist.append(num) # <--- Same as above

print('Number Array:', numlist)
print('Position Array', poslist)
plt.plot(*(poslist, numlist))
plt.show()
```

The other option if you want to use numpy arrays would be to change your lists. If one wanted to use `np.append`, you would use something like `poslist = np.append(poslist, i)`. However, as recommended in the comments to this answer by hpaulj, if you want to use `np.concatenate` it would look like more like `poslist = np.concatenate((poslist, [i,]))`. ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932101/numpy-append-vs-concatenate) compares the two methods.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

poslist = np.array([]) # <--- change list to array
numlist = np.array([]) # <--- change list to array
i = 1

num = int(input('Number to check?'))
plt.title(str(num) + ': Collatz Graph')
plt.xlabel('Step')
plt.ylabel('Value')
print(num)

#poslist = np.append(poslist, i) # <--- Fix syntax of np.append
poslist = np.concatenate((poslist, [i,])) # <-- Or use concatenate instead
numlist = np.concatenate((numlist, [num,])) # <-- Or use concatenate instead

while True:
    i = i + 1
    if num % 2 == 0:
        num = num // 2
        print(num)
    elif num == 1:
        break
    else:
        num = num * 3
        num = num + 1
        print(num)
    poslist = np.concatenate((poslist, [i,])) # <--- Move out of if/else statement
    numlist = np.concatenate((numlist, [num,])) 

print('Number Array:', numlist)
print('Position Array', poslist)
plt.plot(*(poslist, numlist))
plt.show()
```

Comment: We discourage the use of `np.append`, especially in a loop.

Comment: @hpaulj I can understand why this shouldn't be done in a loop, but the comment implies it's always discouraged. Why, specifically, is it discouraged, and who is **we**?

Comment: ``np.append` is a cover for `np.concatenate`.  Too many novices try to use it as a list append clone, getting errors and slow performance.  It's ok when adding a scalar to a 1d array, since it turns the scalar into an array that concatenate can use.  Other than that, I encourage the use of concatenate or one of its `stack` covers.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I have edited my answer suggesting `np.concatenate` based on your feedback. You suggest it would have been okay here since we were adding a scalar, but hopefully this will encourage better practices in the long term. (This is one of the reasons I love SO, you keep learning even when you aren't looking for answers!)