# Why does numpy documentation recommend to prefer concatente over hstack?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Why does numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) recommend to prefer concatente over hstack?

> but you should prefer np.concatenate or np.stack.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356442/when-should-i-use-hstack-vstack-vs-append-vs-concatenate-vs-column-stack) hstack is a wrapper around concatenate. In that case why not use hstack which improves the readability of the code?

Comment: One less frame in the call stack?

Comment: Because if you try to understand them both, you might care less about "readability" and more about performance?

Comment: Probably because the semantics are clearer for array dimensions other than 2.

Answer (score 0):

So the actual code in `hstack` is:

```
arrs = [atleast_1d(_m) for _m in tup]
# As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
else:
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
```

It first loops through the arguments and makes sure that each is at least 1d.  This takes care of the 0d and scalar elements, such as in `np.hstack([0,1,np.arange(3)])`.

The rest chooses between concatenating on the one and only axis or the 2nd one.

`vstack` is similar, except it makes things atleast 2d, and concatenates on the 1st.

Judging from SO questions/answers these are still being used quite a bit, and I think in most cases they don't cause problems.  It's `np.append` that creates most problems. That's the one I wish they'd never added.

I think the main problem with `hstack` and `vstack` is that they encourage (or at least allow) lazy thinking about dimensions and shapes.  When questions arise it's because the poster doesn't understand what is means to have the same number of dimensions, or that shapes must be equal (except for one axis).