# Concatenate multiple numpy array present in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list containing multiple numpy arrays
and i want to concatenate all those numpy arrays. I am doing it manually , the following way

```
f_0_1=np.concatenate((features_0_1[0],features_0_1[1],features_0_1[2],\
features_0_1[3],features_0_1[4],features_0_1[5],features_0_1[6],features_0_1[7]),1)
```

how can i do it in a more better way by using for loop or any thing , actually i dont want to make it hard coded. I just want to concat all the numpy arrays of my list features_0_1.

this is some sort of solution i want

```
for i in range(len(features_0_1)):
    fz=np.concatenate((features_0_1[i],features_0_1[1+i]),1)
```

but this does not give the same answer

Comment: Concatenate along which axis? (i.e. do you want each array to be a column or a row of the result?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when should i use hstack/vstack vs append vs concatenate vs column\_stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356442/when-should-i-use-hstack-vstack-vs-append-vs-concatenate-vs-column-stack)

Comment: @gmds Actually i want to do concatenation, i have update my query, please check that

Comment: @Chris i want to do it along column, i have mentioned it already, axis=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can easily just use:

```
f_0_1 = np.concatenate(features_0_1)
```

As you can see, you dont need to pass each array from ndarray to concatenate(). The function does it on it's own.

Comment: thanks , bu just f_0_1 = np.concatenate(features_0_1,1) my problem is resolved .
there is no need of append even