# What is the difference between concatenate and stack in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am bit confused between both the methods : concatenate and stack

The concatenate and stack provides exactly same output , what is the difference between both of them ?

**Using : concatenate**

```
import numpy as np
my_arr_1 = np.array([ [1,4] ,   [2,7] ])
my_arr_2 = np.array([ [0,5]   , [3,8] ])

join_array=np.concatenate((my_arr_1,my_arr_2),axis=0)
print(join_array)
```

**Using : stack**

```
import numpy as np
my_arr_1 = np.array([ [1,4] ,   [2,7] ])
my_arr_2 = np.array([ [0,5]   , [3,8] ])

join1_array=np.stack((my_arr_1,my_arr_2),axis=0)
print(join1_array)
```

**Output for both is same :**

```
[[[1 4]
  [2 7]]

 [[0 5]
  [3 8]]]
```

Comment: You're using ```np.stack``` in both the code snippets.

Comment: Check this, it probably answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356442/when-should-i-use-hstack-vstack-vs-append-vs-concatenate-vs-column-stack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [160]: my_arr_1 = np.array([ [1,4] ,   [2,7] ])
     ...: my_arr_2 = np.array([ [0,5]   , [3,8] ])
     ...: 
     ...: join_array=np.concatenate((my_arr_1,my_arr_2),axis=0)
In [161]: join_array
Out[161]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 7],
       [0, 5],
       [3, 8]])
In [162]: _.shape
Out[162]: (4, 2)
```

`concatenate` joined the 2 arrays on an existing axis, so the (2,2) become (4,2).

```
In [163]: join1_array=np.stack((my_arr_1,my_arr_2),axis=0)
In [164]: join1_array
Out[164]: 
array([[[1, 4],
        [2, 7]],

       [[0, 5],
        [3, 8]]])
In [165]: _.shape
Out[165]: (2, 2, 2)
```

`stack` joined them on a new axis.  It actually made them both (1,2,2) shape, and then used `concatenate`.

The respective docs should make this clear.

Comment: : can you elaborate the (1,2,2) means  1-> indicate what , 2 indicate what ?

Comment: It should be `(2,2,2)` right ?

Comment: : can you explain this : It actually made them both (1,2,2) shape, and then used concatenate

Comment: look at the code